# UIView frame issue between iPhone 4 & 5

Tags: ios, autoresizingmask

In my XIB, I set the view size to Retina 3.5 and set "Use Autolayout" to off.

Programmatically, I created a UIImageView and drew it at Y coordinate of 316 with autoresizingMask set to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin .

When testing the view on the iPhone 5 simulator, the UIImageView is at the bottom of the view (where it should be). 
During runtime I draw the exact same UIImageView at the same Y coordinate and setting autoresizingMask to UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin as well. 
The new UIImageView is drawn not at the same location (at the bottom of the view) as the first UIImageView.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Oded.

Answer (score 0):

It depends when you add the subview (before or after the superview is auto-resized). In any event, if you're laying out your view so it's static pinned to the bottom you should calculate the `y` position from the `heigth`s of the super and subviews and then it doesn't matter whether it's done before or after.

Comment: The first subview is set inside the ViewDidLoad method but after the [super viewDidLoad] call and it's set in the correct place (the Y coordinate is calculated from the view.frame.size.height property). The second subview's frame is copied from the first subview's frame, and is drawn no at the bottom.

Comment: So the frame is copied from an existing view, the auto-resizing mask is identical and the superviews are the same?